# How to calculate the remaining days left for a persons next birthday from the date pickers selected date in android?

Tags: android, date

I have written a program to calculate the age of a person according to the date selected from the date picker , and its working fine. 
Now i added another method to display just the days remaining and the day on which the persons birthday falls on his next birthday

```
private void calculateNextBirthday() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Date dt = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy/MM/dd");
    final String strBDay = sdf.format(dt);
    try {

        dt = sdf.parse(strBDay);
    } catch (final java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTime(dt);
    // c.add(Calendar.DATE, value);
    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Take your DOB Month and compare it to current
    // month
    final int BMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
                today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    if (BMonth <= CMonth) {
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,
                    today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
    }
    // Result in millis

    final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
                        - today.getTimeInMillis();
    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated
                                                    // (24 *
                                                    // 60 *
                                                    // 60 *
                                                    // 1000)
    // final String dayOfTheWeek =
    // sdf.format(BDay.getTime());
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    final String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(dt);
    txt8.setText("" + days + " days");
    txt10.setText("" + dayOfTheWeek);
}
```

The problem in this program is the remaining days left works on the basis of todays date but not from the dates selected from the date picker, means even if i select any other date from the date picker the remaining days remains the same and the dayoftheweek also shows the same , i want both to change according the dates selected

also attaching the 2 screenshots with two different birthdates and the output is same on the last two rows of my screenshot

[image]
[image]

My program shows the age of the person correctly when selected any date from the date picker , in the same way i would want my remaining days and the day on which the persons birthday falls to change, to when selected any date from the date picker
please need some help as to what changes i need to do in the above code 
any suggestions would be helpful
thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is:

You are calculating difference using current date.

See a little modified function:

```
private void calculateNextBirthday() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    /*Date dt = new Date();  //this is just current date, which was causing issue. It should be user selected date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy/MM/dd");
    final String strBDay = sdf.format(dt);
    try {

        dt = sdf.parse(strBDay);
    } catch (final java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(1990, 8, 03);  //this is birthdate. set it to date you get from date picker
    // c.add(Calendar.DATE, value);
    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Take your DOB Month and compare it to current
    // month
    final int BMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    final int BDate = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int CDate = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
                today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    if (BMonth < CMonth) {
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR,
                    today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
    }
    //added this condition so that it doesn't add in case birthdate is greater than current date . i.e. yet to come in this month. 
    else if (BMonth == CMonth){
        if(BDate < CDate){
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR,
                    today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
        }
    }
    // Result in millis

    final long millis = c.getTimeInMillis()
                        - today.getTimeInMillis();
    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated
                                                    // (24 *
                                                    // 60 *
                                                    // 60 *
                                                    // 1000)
    // final String dayOfTheWeek =
    // sdf.format(BDay.getTime());
    /*sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    final String dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(dt);*/
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(days), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir thank you the remaining days works perfectly , but sir the day is not changing , it always shows wednesday , and sir the days remaining which is changing it is changing every week , means like from 25th nov 2014 to 2nd dec 2014 it shows the same days remaining ,it only changes after a week, but i want to change it everyday , i know its because of the DAY_OF_WEEK , what to do sir ?

Comment: You need to pass date properly. @arjunnarahari

Comment: what if I want the formats to be like 4 months and 5 days remaining until your next birthday.